# [Terraform]: Create Athena database in S3 bucket with different prefix for different environment

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-athena

I'm trying to use terraform to provision 3 athena databases. These database are going to sit in same S3 bucket but just different path inside the bucket.

- my_athena (prod): path: s3://my_s3_bucket/
- my_athena_uat (uat): path: s3://my_s3_bucket/uat
- my_athena_dev (dev): path: s3://my_s3_bucket/dev

I checked the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/athena_database) in terraform but can't seem find an attribute supporting the sub-directory.

Would anyone be able to advise?

P.S: I understand it's probably not a best practice to put all 3 database in same bucket but it happened for some reasons I don't want to address now.

Comment: There's no option for that. It's not possible. It's also a really bad idea in general to share a bucket for dev/uat/prod. S3 buckets are free, and you can create as many as you want. You only pay for the objects in the bucket, and spreading them across 3 buckets would be the same cost as having them all in one bucket, so there is no good reason to bundle multiple environments in a single bucket.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @MarkB. I understand it's not a good practice but this is just one of the many legacy issues I inherited. I can only tackle one at a time.